# Why is this video showing radio waves transmitted from a radio telescope?

Tags: radio-astronomy

I saw this video at [Space.com](http://www.space.com/32055-mystery-fast-radio-burst-space-explosions-location.html) and I noticed that at 00:05 the animation illustrates waves propagating from space into [The Dish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkes_Observatory) at Parks Observatory, but at 00:50 the direction of propagation is reversed! Would there be some reason for transmitting - for example to create an [artificial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_guide_star) "star" for wavefront correction analogous to [adaptive optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_optics) at visible wavelengths, or could it be simply a mistake in the animation?

Here are some GIFs from screenshots. You can check the [video](http://www.space.com/32055-mystery-fast-radio-burst-space-explosions-location.html) at the indicated times.

**circa 00:05**

[image: at 00:05]

**circa 00:50**

[image]

Comment: Its just a slightly dodgy graphic. No astronomical meaning.

Comment: If you are sure @JamesKilfiger , can you add some supporting information and post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: There's a lesson to be learned here: Youtube (along with other websites that dish out videos, pun intended) is not the place to learn science.

Comment: Maybe the lesson is really "consider the source." YouTube is just a library - you can browse the "tabloids", or go to the "bookshelves" for the good stuff. Plenty of top notch stuff available there. Note @DavidHammen - the source for the link in this question is a private, advertisement-laden site.

Comment: Consider the source -- That is exactly right. Any decent layperson's site that publishes a key scientific discovery will inevitably provide links to the underlying scientific journal papers in which those discoveries were first announced. space.com rarely, if ever, does this. It is not a good source.

Comment: screen shot of what I mean by "[advertisement-laden](http://i.imgur.com/3jvBp6O.png)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's a mistake in the animation. At radio wavelengths turbulence doesn't affect the measurments anymore and above 200 MHz the ionosphere doesn't play a role yet, so I guess the notion of a guide star is unnecessary here.

Comment: Thanks! That was a "*for example*" only: "*Would there be some reason for transmitting - for example to create...*". I'd like to find out for sure if there is some transmission of some kind, or if the video is wrong.

Comment: @uhoh: Yeah sorry, I cannot tell about any other transmissions for sure, as I'm not a radio astronomer.

Comment: Now you've [got me thinking!](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13930/7982) Thanks!